# Inheriting methods in a class

Tags: python-3.x

We have three class (A,B and C), class A and B is having add method, class C we are inherating from class A and class B. So from class C if i call add method which add method will called first. Class A add method or class B add method in python.

Answer (score 0):

In multiple inheritance order, last modification, how you call method matter. [Good to read and try](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-python/)

Comment: @SoumyaranjanDash welcome on SO! If answer was useful, please accept it.